# Pallet declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(0)`

Tags: runtime-upgrade, frontier, migration, on-runtime-upgrade

After a runtime upgrade on Frontier, these warnings are logged:
[image]

In this case, the pallets are related to Frontier only, but that seems possible for any FRAME pallets.

Does anything need to be done regarding these warnings? Do they mean some kind of storage migration is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a runtime upgrade happens, if the runtime contains some pallet that implements `on_runtime_upgrade` (like `ethereum` pallet [does](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/c2b56a8f3097826c85f23a16b744cec99335530d/frame/ethereum/src/lib.rs#L273)), these warnings will show up.

These warnings can be safely ignored. They do not mean a storage migration is needed.

Comment: Also, a sane migration will only happen if the current and onchain `StorageVersion`  don't match, which in this case they do. This is why they are being printed.

Answer (score 1):

After you update the ethereum's version in cargo dependency, maybe this will be removed (if the latest code has updated the storage version in code.).